# html2image configuration in java

Tags: java, html

I would to ask about html2image, i have some codes like this

```
import gui.ava.html.image.generator.HtmlImageGenerator;
import java.io.File;


public class html2image {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
        imageGenerator.loadHtml("<b>Hello World!</b> Please goto <a title=\"Goto Google\" href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>."); 
        imageGenerator.saveAsImage("hello-world.png"); 
        imageGenerator.saveAsHtmlWithMap("hello-world.html", "hello-world.png");
    }
}
```

But seems like after i call this java, its not appear any image or output image, maybe i miss some configuration, anyone can help ?

Comment: You'd have to look at the documentation of `HtmlImageGenerator` to know what it is doing or what status information you can get. Without knowing it I'd assume the file (if any is generated) is put into the current working directory which should be the directory from which you run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the absolute path in  **imageGenerator.saveAsImage** as otherwise the file will be generated in the working directory.